# VS code, c++ extension, task.json is there a way to group args in a array and reference in a task

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Im using VS code with c++ extesion, on my task.json i have a debug task and runwithoutdebug task, this tasks have common arguments and i instead of have to add those arguments in both, i was trying to reference a array, and write those common argument in that array.

Is that possible? is there any alternative

Example:  --->task.json

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {    ---------------------->  TASK 1

        "label": "compilewithoutDeb",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "main.cpp",
            "header.cpp",
            "-o",
            "main.exe" 
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }

    },
    {    ---------------------->  TASK 2
        "label": "compileDeb",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "main.cpp",
            "header.cpp",
            "-o",
            "main.exe" 
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

Has you can see i have on task "compilewithoutDeb" and "compileDeb" this common arguments

```
"main.cpp",
"header.cpp",
"-o",
"main.exe"
```

Is there a away that i could do like:

```
 "paramArg":[
    "main.cpp",
    "header.cpp",
    "-o",
    "main.exe" 
 ]


"tasks": [
    {

        "label": "compilewithoutDeb",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "${paramArg}"  <-----------------
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an input.  It would be a promptString with the arguments as the default.  For your other task you'd add the "-g" parameter before the input.

```
"tasks": [
    {

        "label": "compilewithoutDeb",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "${input:paramArg}"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }, 
    {

        "label": "compileDeb",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g", 
            "${input:paramArg}"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }, 
], 
"inputs": [
    {
        "id": "paramArg", 
        "description": "Just hit the Enter key", 
        "type": "promptString", 
        "default": "main.cpp header.cpp -o main.exe"
    }, 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's an (ugly) way to do this. While tasks.json can only define tasks (that is what is is for) it can reference [different kind of variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference).

The two options that would be reasonable to use: `env` (if you want to set it outside of vscode which doesn't seem to be the case here) or [`config`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_configuration-variables).

To apply it to your sample:

settings.json (either in your user's settings or in the workspace [folder .vscode])

```
{
  "personalSettings.commonArgs": [
    "-o",
    "main.exe", 
    "header.cpp",
    "main.cpp"
  ]
}
```

and then your tasks.json would be

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        { // ---------------------->  TASK 1
            "label": "compilewithoutDeb",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++ ${config:personalSettings.commonArgs}",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        { // ---------------------->  TASK 2
            "label": "compileDeb",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++ ${config:personalSettings.commonArgs}",
            "args": [
                "-g"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

(additional changes: only one build task can be the default, used inline comments)

Note: to get the most out of your build tasks I'd suggest to add a problem matcher to your task definition, something like

```
            // use this or similar when cpptools or a similar libre/free extension
            // is installed providing an appropriate matcher
            // "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
            // remark: ms-vscode.cpptools is "gratis", but comes with telemetry + usage-restrictions
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
```

Note: I'd suggest to not hard-wire the file names, instead use either a "general task" which uses `${file}` or change the tool you run to make where you have all the arguments defined clean, *can* build outside of vscode, too and because of dependency tracking only compile what is actually necessary.

Comment: Note: you may want to vote on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97600 to get this builtin-definition without the need to install extensions (the complete syntax highlighting is built-in - and that is huge when compared to the problemMatcher) or manually define it.